# If it carries out, how can an addition and deletion of application be performed using MDM?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I am using "APNs" of Apple, and "MDM". 
The list of applications is also acquirable from the iOS terminal using "MDM". 
But, an addition and deletion of application can not be performed. 
The error message that there is nothing under management of "MDM" is displayed. 
It is the application of the self created by the enterprise that I am trying to perform an addition and deletion of application.

It does not come out of an error message.

Iphone Configuration Manager Utility (IPCU). 
Below has a log.

```
May 23 04:51:18 iPhone mdmd[1134] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: mdmd starting...
May 23 04:51:18 iPhone profiled[1135] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service starting...
May 23 04:51:18 iPhone mdmd[1134] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Network reachability has changed.
May 23 04:51:18 iPhone mdmd[1134] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Network reachability has changed.
May 23 04:51:18 iPhone mdmd[1134] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Polling MDM server https://www.anetm.com/davtest/pro.php for commands
May 23 04:51:18 iPhone mdmd[1134] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Transaction completed. Status: 200
May 23 04:51:19 iPhone mdmd[1134] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Transaction completed. Status: 200
May 23 04:51:21 iPhone mdmd[1134] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: mdmd stopping...
```

However, application is not installed.

"InstallApplication" is being used for the payload by "Managed Application" of MDM Protocol Reference.

If it carries out, how can an addition and deletion of application be performed using MDM?

Comment: Thank you! "Brad Larson"

Comment: @Makoto: Where you able to get install application through MDM profile working? I am running into issue you had reported before, i do not get an error just empty request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the installed MDM payload allows application management under the `AccessRights` key. Once the MDM payload with that access right has been installed, you can push an app to the managed device using the `InstallApplication` command. If the app being pushed is an iTunes app, you will need the app's iTunes  store id number. For more details, see Apple's "Mobile Device Management Protocol Reference" document.

Going into more detail, when an iOS device accepts an MDM payload and agrees to be managed by an MDM system, that payload will contain a list of "access rights" that the managed device agrees to allow. This list is displayed when the iOS device starts the MDM enrollment process giving the user a chance to cancel if the user feels she is granting the MDM management system too much control.

In iOS 5 there is a new access right for application management that allows the "pushing" of iTunes applications, or local "enterprise" applications. (Note that the iOS device user has to agree each time an app is pushed.) If that right is not included in the original MDM enrollment payload, the MDM system cannot manage apps.

Comment: I have lodged the addition of application, and the power of deletion in the right to access. 
And it also checked that the composition profile was normally installed in a terminal. 
However, application cannot be added. 
I want you to help.

Comment: Try this: connect your phone to your desktop via the USB cable, start the Iphone Configuration Manager Utility (IPCU), send the `InstallApplication` command to a phone and watch what your phone does in the IPCU console window. If you get an error message, post it here.

Comment: Thank you. 

It does not come out of an error message. 

Iphone Configuration Manager Utility (IPCU). 
Below has a log. 


May 23 04:51:18 iPhone mdmd[1134] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: mdmd starting...
May 23 04:51:18 iPhone profiled[1135] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service starting...
May 23 04:51:18 iPhone mdmd[1134] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Network reachability has changed.
May 23 04:51:18 iPhone mdmd[1134] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Network reachability has changed.
May 23 04:51:18 iPhone mdmd[1134] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Polling

Comment: May 23 04:51:18 iPhone mdmd[1134] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Transaction completed. Status: 200
May 23 04:51:19 iPhone mdmd[1134] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Transaction completed. Status: 200
May 23 04:51:21 iPhone mdmd[1134] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: mdmd stopping...

However, application is not installed. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [airwatch-mdm-agent](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/airwatch-mdm-agent/id338761996?mt=8) application. The iTunes store id is 338761996
and then check the device log.
If installation is successful then try to remove this application by sending MDM command.

Refer [this](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Documents/mobile_device_management_protocol/mobiledevicemanagement_121211.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. 
Since I am not using vpp, can't I use?

Comment: Thank you. 
It was not installed although tried. 
Has it made a mistake in some? 

<key>iTunesStoreID</key><number>338761996</number>

Comment: I had the same issue but just found a solution , when i looked into man page i see CFNumber is mapped to real or integer tags , once changed it to real it worked like a charm https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html